# How to change a code page of thermal printer

Tags: android, printing, thermal-printer, pos

I found and compile an example of Android app for printing receipt on [Bluetooth thermal printer ZCS103](http://www.szzcs.com/prod_view.aspx?TypeId=79&Id=177). But I cannot change code page for printing Russian chars. The device prints English and Chinese characters only.

[Source code of test Android app](https://github.com/SergeyUr/BluetoothThermalPrinterSDK-)

Can you help me with it?

Comment: Hello.. Have you solved this?

Comment: Hello, no. I don't have any solution for it...